How to limit the amount of identical logs in an endless loop?
I have a C# program that starts as follows:
while (true)
...

You can imagine that, when adding a log entry on a certain places, that the risk exists that it gets written millions of times, blowing up my logfiles, which I would like to avoid.
Is this possible? Is there some configuration like "Amount of identical logs to be outputted, even if the timestamps are different"?
If yes, how to use it?
For your information, hereby the Logger definition:
#region Assembly NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c
// C:\...\packages\NLog.4.6.0\lib\net45\NLog.dll
...
namespace NLog;

//
// Summary:
//     Provides logging interface and utility functions.
[CLSCompliant(true)]
public class Logger : ILogger, ILoggerBase, ISuppress

For your information, hereby the LogManager definition:
#region Assembly NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c
// C:\...\packages\NLog.4.6.0\lib\net45\NLog.dll
...
namespace NLog;

//
// Summary:
//     Creates and manages instances of NLog.Logger objects.
public static class LogManager

Typical usage of the _logger:
using NLog;
...
private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
...
_logger.Debug($"SendMove: from here=[{this.Name}] to loc=[{loc.Name}]");

The typical example I'm looking for, looks as follows:
if (some_object != null)
{
    _logger.Debug($"SendMove: from here=[{this.Name}] to loc=[{loc.Name}]");
}
else
{
    _logger.Debug("some_object is null");
}

Currently I only have the successful case in my logging, but I would also like to see the unsuccessful one, but this would result in following logging file:
...
SendMove: from here=[home] to loc=[dest]
some_object is null
some_object is null
some_object is null
... // thousands or millions of times, making the whole logfile unreadable
some_object is null
...

I would like my logs to look more or less like (as proposed by Sinatr):
...
SendMove: from here=[home] to loc=[dest]
some_object is null
this error has occured 12938 times since
...

Further on this site, I found a similar question, advising the following configuration:
<target ... queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">

... but having a look at my application, I don't see those queueLimit nor overflowAction properties:
Source code:
var test = LogManager.GetLogger("test");

Watch window:

Decompiling my NLog.dll learned me that FileTarget is a TargetWithLayoutHeaderAndFooter, which is a TargetWithLayout, which is a Target, while the mentioned queueLimit and overflowAction seem to belong to AsyncTaskTarget, which is not in the mentioned inheritance tree.
Why not?
Other proposal:
Of course, if NLog would remember the last logged message, I might program it myself:
if (!(_logger.last_log_message().StartsWith("some_object is null"))
{
    _logger.Debug("some_object is null (possible multiple times)");
}

Does such a thing exist?

We need to see your actual logging code, and how you're using NLog.

@Dai: thanks a lot for your quick reply! I've edited my question accordingly.

Those changes don't really help - what is the relationship between your while(true) loop and static class LogManager?

"adding a log entry on a certain places" - I guess you need to fix those places individually, so they can't spam. Throttle technique may do: "this error has occured 12938 times since".

@Sinatr: by "individually", do you mean that I need to configure every logging individually? I would prefer a general solution, if possible.

This answer suggests to write a tool for viewing big logs.

@Sinatr: my question is not a duplicate of the post you mention: in that post, something was run once but it was logged multiple times, which was wrong. In my case something will be run a lot and I would like it to be logged less (like one time and then the throttle phrase you proposed).

@Sinatr: however, I found another question with exactly the same question, but the solution, provided in that question, is not applicable for me. Any idea why?

@Sinatr: as far as "This answer" is concerned: the answer to that question has been written in 2011, I'm hoping that NLog might have added some features by now.

As this might be a change request for NLog, I've written a post for this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/5539

While I sympathize with the issue, it's hard to see how NLog could automatically determine what makes a log entry redundant and thus eligible for elimination. It seems to me there would need to be some sort of rule language.

@500-InternalServerError: I would say this is very easy: just create a buffer, containing a counter, and once a log message is sent three times or more, just write it once or twice and when another message is sent to NLog, write a message, mentioning the number of occurences.

@Dominique " and when another message is sent to NLog, write a message, mentioning the number of occurences" How would you do that for, say, a logfile? Keep re-writing the last line? That's horribly inefficient. And how about the windows eventlog, where you can't even update an entry? That would give you thousands of new entries of "last message repeated 1 times", "last message repeated 2 times", "last message repeated ... times". And what if you log to, say, email or syslog? How would NLog handle that?

Having said that; it's trivial to create some sort of a 'buffered logger' that just buffers the last X messages and only outputs a message whenever it's not a duplicate. That would mean you get a delay in your log messages and may lose messages on shutdown or crashes - which is when you need logging most.

@RobIII: I'm not asking to write the last X messages, but to write the first one, followed by a message, saying how much times that message has been repeated. In case of a crashing application, the application can altered (or its NLog configuration) in order to repeat the messages.

Unless you have a time-traveling machine you'll have to buffer message after emitting the first one (d'uh) to get the count of the repeated messages, right? You could even flush the buffered messages at some interval, but either way you're gonna have to buffer.

@RobIII: indeed, as I said: "* just create a buffer*..."

@Dominique Then what is your question if you already know you need (some sort of a) buffered logger?

@RobIII: I would like to know if the logger of NLog already covers buffering and how I should use it.

@Dominique I literally linked to a buffered logger here. If you want a logger that counts repeated messages - which, to me, is your actual question - then I think you'll need to implement it yourself since NLog doesn't provide that functionality as far as I'm aware. EDIT: Actually: it does - sort of.

You could write a buffered logger that, in pseudocode, does something like this:
class DeduplicatingLogger extends baselogger {
  lastmessage = ""
  repeatcount = 0;

  void LogMessage(string message) {
    if (message != lastmessage) {
      if (repeatcount > 0) {
        base.LogMessage("last message repeated <repeatcount> times")
      }

      base.LogMessage(message)
      lastmessage = message
      repeatcount = 0
    } else {
      repeatcount++
    }
  }
}

You could 'flush' the buffer at some interval X (say, 10 minutes) and you should make sure the buffer gets flushed on dispose / shutdown.
Edit: Or.... just use the WhenRepeated filter as I editted here.

My answer relies on your willingness to rethink your architecture a bit, but should still work.
Provided you are in favor of modernizing your codebase, my recommendation would be to migrate towards using OpenTelemetry C# libraries for your logs, paired with an OpenTelemetry Collector instance. Then, you can employ sampling for the logs in the collector using one of the native samplers, like this one:

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/probabilisticsamplerprocessor/README.md

As you can see from the documentation, it is currently in alpha support for log spans, so keep that in mind.
This approach would mitigate your problem of a large log file by filtering the log events prior to writing them to the destination (be it a file, or some observability platform). This does have a cost however in that sampling is performed out of process, so you end up incurring the cost of writing the log, and sending it to the collector, only for it to be ignored there.
I don't believe there is a native .NET sampling abstraction for logs quite yet, like there is for traces with Activity sampling, so this is as far as you can go without changing the logic too much further.
Alternatively, you could tap into the native Activity sampling by converting your logs into "activity events": instead of writing raw log entries, you write events to the current Activity, which are then propagated as part of the trace and can be directly influenced by the native sampling the framework provides (for example, using the TraceIdRatio sampler). You can check the current native sampler implementations here for more details:

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/docs/trace/customizing-the-sdk/README.md#samplers

When using Activity like this, you not only save on the actual size and network/file operations required to send/write the logs, but you also save in actual performance in the application, as sampling directly affects the running code to conditionally write traces and events only when the activity is going to be sampled.
This can be achieved by checking the IsAllDataRequested property in the Activity object in your code right before writing your custom event to it: if the sampler has decided not to sample that activity, this property will return false and you can avoid the event logging logic altogether. This makes for an extremely efficient pipeline for critical code paths like your loop, as the act of writing the log itself can start to become a bottleneck. This also obviously saves the entire roundtrip to an external collector as you are now filtering in-process.
From your original post, it seems to me like you are still using a somewhat primitive form of logging, so this is why these approaches would require you to re-evaluate your observability pipeline in more detail and move into more modern forms of telemetry which are substantially more flexible.
Regardless of your particular issue, I'd still recommend moving into OpenTelemetry for any serious modern application.

The best way to avoid duplicate logging, is to not produce duplicate logging.
Maybe like this:
DateTime lastTime = DateTime.MinValue;
int skippedLogging = 0;
while (true)
{
   var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
   if ((currentTime - lastTime).TotalSeconds >= 1.0)
   {
        Logger.Info("Frequent logging output. Repeated={0}", skippedLogging);
        lastTime = currentTime;
        skippedLogging = 0;
   }
   else
   {
        ++skippedLogging;
   }
}

But for application where you are not able to modify the source-code, then one can consider to use the WhenRepeated-Filter
